# Locking shapefiles from editing by ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, editing, security

How we can lock or protect a shapefile from editing in arcgis?

I want another person to be able to view the data/attributes in the shapefile, but don't want them to be able to change or edit the data.

Comment: Your best bet might be to set the files that make up the shapefile to be read only.  This would prevent them from being modified.  I would say to make the directory read only, except ArcGIS needs to be able to place a lock file in the directory when a shapefile is accessed, so that step probably wouldn't work.

Comment: does it need to be a shapefile?  File geodatabase allows you to compress which makes the data read-only